# How can I extend and add to the IFormFile Interface in .NET Core. Need to append data to the serialised array when submitting an ajax request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, model-binding

I need to upload a file using .net core.

I am using a multipart form and AJAX.

However I have a unique requirement. I need to be able to add data to the serialized array and then bind it to the controller through an ajax POST request and Model Binding.

I need to add an id, which i pass to the controller. Based on the id I decide to which row in a table I save the uploaded file details.

My Controller to which I am Posting:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> File(List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);


            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();


            foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }
                }
            }

            string fpath = filePath;

            var query = from d in db.TableA
                        where d.File == null && d.id == id // This is where I need to compare the ID
                        select d;


            foreach (TableA details in query)
            {
                details.File = filePath;
            }
            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync(); // await needed to hold execution
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);

            }


            return RedirectToAction("View");
        }
```

> where d.File == null && d.id == id // This is where I need to compare
>   the ID

Multi Part Form:

```
<form method="post" id="typea" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Main" asp-action="File">
<label class="btn btn-info"> Upload your document <input type="file" name="files" onchange="this.form.submit()" hidden />
</label>
</form>
```

My Ajax call:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#typea').click(function () {


            event.preventDefault();


            var $form = $(this);
            var serializedData = $form.serializeArray();
            serializedData.push({ name: "ID", value: "typea" });
            $.ajax({
                url: "Main/File",
                type: "POST",
                data: serializedData

            });

        });
```

My problem is this:

If i push the array I cannot count on IFormFile Interface for model binding.

Can I somehow extend the IFormFIle interface?

Or is there a way I can do it without using the IFormFile.
I tried to write my own model referencing from the IFormFIle interface but could not.

```
public interface IFormFile
{
    string ContentType { get; }
    string ContentDisposition { get; }
    IHeaderDictionary Headers { get; }
    long Length { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string FileName { get; }
    Stream OpenReadStream();
    void CopyTo(Stream target);
    Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null);
}
```

I could not use the methods of the interface, which is obvious.
Pointers please :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You don't need to implements (extends) the `IFormFile` interface, a wrapper by composition is preferred over inheritance. Simply create a dummy POCO to  hold the information :

   ```
   public class IFormFilesWrapper{

       public string Id {get;set;}  // you might change the type to Guid / int /e.t.c

       public IList<IFormFile> Files {get;set;}
   }
   ```

   and the action method will be :

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> File(IFormFilesWrapper filesWrapper)
   {
       var id = filesWrapper.Id;  // here's the Id posted by client

       long size = filesWrapper.Files.Sum(f => f.Length);

       var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

       foreach (var formFile in filesWrapper.Files)
       {
           if (formFile.Length > 0)
           {
               using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
               {
                   await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
               }
           }
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```
2. As a side note, if I remember correctly, the `$form.serializeArray()` doesn't work well for `multipart/form-data`. So I use a plain `FormData` to generate the payload :

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#typea>button').click(function () {

           event.preventDefault();

           var form = document.querySelector("#typea");
           var formData = new FormData(form);
           formData.append("ID","typea");

           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.open("POST","Main/File");
           xhr.send(formData);
       });
   });
   ```

A screenshot :

[image]

Comment: @it,inus
Hi, The above solution worked spledidly, thank you.
However it worked only for one submission. Therefore I have removed it outside document.ready() and attached it to a submit handler. Now I am getting an error saying "Content" attribute of windows object is depreciated. This is what i have done:

Comment: `<form method="post" id="typea" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Main" asp-action="File">
                                              <label class="btn btn-info">
                                                  Upload your document <input type="file" name="files" onchange="this.form.submit()" hidden />
                                              </label>

                                          </form>`

Comment: `$('#typea').submit(function (event) {

                event.preventDefault();

                var form = document.querySelector("#typea");
                var formData = new FormData(form);
                formData.append("ID", "typea");

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "Main/File");
                xhr.send(formData);
            });`

could you help, thankyou:)

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna, don't submit the form, simply add a button and use it to trigger ajax : document.querySelector("#your_button").onclick= function(){ /* ... */ }

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna  If you still cannot figure it out , please feel free to comment;  or when I can access my desktop tomorrow , I'll show you a complete code.

Comment: Hi tried the following:
`var file = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");  
  file.addEventListener("change", function () {...ajax};`
As I understand what is happening is the input tag is used to upload a file and **onchange** function is used to submit a the form .i.e. as soon as the file is uploaded, the status changes and thus `onchange="this.form.submit()"` submits the form. If i dont submit the form how will the file data be captured?Also this worked perfectly the first time and was posting data to the controller,the second time I am facing problems. Sorry if silly:)ty

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna, if you submit the form , the server will response with a new page. So It's better to use ajax to post the payload to server, namely use the code `var form = document.querySelector("#typea");
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        formData.append("ID","typea");

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST","Main/File");
        xhr.send(formData);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183882/discussion-between-itminus-and-abhilash-gopalakrishna).